# How to Store Date in sql server 2005 using java

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, prepared-statement

I am trying to store date in sql server 2005

i am used "datetime" data type in sql server

and in java program i am passing string as date

ex.

```
String Date = "12/12/2013";
String sql = "INSERT INTO info (date) VALUES ( ? )";

try {
      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      pstmt.setString(1, Date); // or pstmt.setDate(1, Date); both not working
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
     }
```

i think String Need to be converted into DateTime Format but i don't know how to do it.
please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your column in the database is in datetime datatype so you need to use `pstmt.setDate(1, Date);` **not** `pstmt.setString(1, Date);`

**Alternate solution**
Well your column is in datetime datatype so you need to store time also
try this way

```
Date d=new Date();
java.sql.Date  d1=new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
String sql = "INSERT INTO info (date) VALUES ( ? )";

try {
      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       pstmt.setDate(1, d1); 
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
     }
```

Comment: it gives error in netbean "incompatible type String Can not be converted to date"

Comment: @Nilesh12 yes it will give you error,because you need to pass date objects.

Comment: now it gives error java.util.date cannot be converted to java.sql.date

Comment: yeh bro thnx it's working for storing date into database but now i want to store String like "12/12/2013" into date type so it means it need to be converted into date so how to do that

Comment: @Nilesh12 If its working then you can accept my answer now.Well you can use simpledateformat for your 2ns question

Comment: can you tell me how to do it i tried SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 d = sdf.parse(Date);

Comment: @Nilesh12 well friend,I can help you but can not write the codes here because my answer will be different for the question you have asked.Can you post another question for the same?